# PySerial read() in a thread takes a long time on Python 3 (.8.5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I have been using PySerial (3.4) very happily in Windows(10)-based Python scripting to talk with embedded targets for a few years now.  With the post-imminent demise of Python 2 I have recently moved all my Python 2.7.15 scripts to Python 3, deciding to go straight to Python 3.8.5.  However, I have encountered what appears to be a problem with PySerial `read()` when run on Python 3.8.5.

**Scenario:**
I have target HW which is streaming output to the COM port that is being read by the script at 115,200, no flow control.  I know the target is behaving because I can see it being read continuously, no lags/delays, with the Python 2.7.15 version of my script and I can also see it in PuTTY.  The output consists of lines of ASCII text terminated by "\r\n" all streamed together.  However under Python 3.8.5 (PySerial 3.4) `read(1)` is taking about 30 ms to return with each character (measured by dumping the difference between `time()` before and after the `read(1)` call into a list) so that receiving 30 characters is taking about 1 second.  Yes, I know that single character reads are inefficient but they definitely ain't *this* inefficient; I would like to be in control of the search for the line ending and, since the character is already there in a Windows buffer, it should return quickly (and does under Python 2).

Has anyone else seen a problem of this nature?  It could, of course, be something to do with Python 3 threading behaviour.  I could try a different Python 3 version but I have a relatively large structure of Python scripts to move so it would need to be a worthwhile bet.  I have raised an issue on PySerial but I fear it may no longer be actively maintained.

EDIT: if I take my `read(1)` out of its thread then it works at the same speed as it did on Python 2.7, so the issue is not with PySerial it is something to do with how threading has changed in Python 3.

**Detail:**
I open the serial port as follows:

```
in_handle = serial.Serial("COM8", 115200, timeout=0.05)
```

...and then I have a function running in a thread which reads `in_handle` as follows:

```
        terminator = "\r"
        line = ""
        eol = False
        return_value = None

        try:
            while not eol and line is not None:
                buf = in_handle.read(1)
                if buf:
                    character = buf.decode('ascii')
                    eol = character == terminator
                    if not eol:
                        line = line + character
                else:
                    line = None
            if eol:
                line = line.strip()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # Just ignore it.
            pass
        return_value = line
```

The output from this is placed on a queue:

```
read_queue.put(return_value)
```

...and the main thread creates the queue/serial-read-thread and de-queues stuff from it with:

```
    read_queue = queue.Queue()
    readline_thread = threading.Thread(target=readline_and_queue,
                                       args=(in_handle))
    readline_thread.start()

    while True:
        try:
            line = read_queue.get(block=False, timeout=0.5)
            # do something with the result
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
```

When I use `time()` either side of the `read(1)` call to measure its duration the values I get for a line that is 34 characters long are:

```
0.03198051452636719
0.031983137130737305
0.031981468200683594
0.0159909725189209
0.031981706619262695
0.0319819450378418
0.0479733943939209
0.031982421875
0.0319826602935791
0.03198075294494629
0.031982421875
0.0319819450378418
0.0319826602935791
0.0159912109375
0.0159909725189209
0.03198122978210449
0.0319819450378418
0.0319821834564209
0.0319821834564209
0.0319821834564209
0.030982255935668945
0.03098273277282715
0.031981706619262695
0.0319826602935791
0.0319821834564209
0.031981706619262695
0.0319819450378418
0.0319819450378418
0.0319821834564209
0.0319828987121582
0.03198075294494629
0.031983375549316406
0.031981468200683594
0.0319821834564209
```

Comment: And it turns out that I can still run the updated script on Python 2 so if I change my path so that I'm running Python27 again, sure enough, it runs at the expected speed (each `read(1)` taking between 5 and 10 ms).  What is going on with Python 3 for me?!

Comment: Fixed it!  My own stupid error: for reasons I don't recall now I had made the dequeue non-blocking, so Python was tearing around that loop pointlessly using up CPU.  Question is, why the devil wasn't this a problem in Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, my own stupid error: for reasons I don't recall now I had made the dequeue non-blocking, so Python was tearing around that loop pointlessly using up CPU. Question is, why the devil wasn't this a problem in Python 2?